# How is using JS to change value of textarea different to user input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textarea

This is a little bit of a mystery to me but I'm sure someone with more JS knowhow will be able to clear this up. There is a large online forum site I use. Back in time I could easily change a comment-element (textarea) via JS, i.e.

```
document.querySelector("textarea").value = "foo"
```

then I'd click the save-button either by hand or script and it would save as you'd expect.

That site redesigned their whole front end a while back. When I do the exact same action now the change is not saved. The moment I activate the change action the original value is rendered.

My question is how do they do it? How do they differentiate if it was a user input or a script that changed the value?

- The textarea DOM element is the only thing that changes
- Nothing in the Redux happens differently
- I tried dispatching a keydown but that did not do the trick either
- Only if I actually click into the comment field and press a button the changes are saved correctly

Comment: I can't tell for sure but they could be checking if the events are trusted with "Event.prototype.isTrusted", so events triggered by scripts won't work, in that case.

Comment: Is there any way to circumvent that?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `domElem.value` doesn't trigger any events on the DOM element.
If you want to simulate any event then you have to trigger the event manually through `domElem.dispatchEvent`.

for example:
If you want to simulate keypress 'a' you have to write something like this.

```js
document.querySelector("#name").value = 'a'
document.querySelector("#name").dispatchEvent(
  new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { key: 'a' })
)

// or if you want to trigger onchange event you have to do something like this.

document.querySelector("#name").dispatchEvent(
  new KeyboardEvent('change', { key: 'a' })
)
```

```html
<input id="name" type="text" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as I wrote in my question I tried that and it does not work.